# C++ - Vector of precise time

Tags: c++

I was looking for a clock in C++ with a good precision and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23000049/3616601) who use the chrono library from std. I then tried to put all durations in a vector. And I've some problems. Here is a simple test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <chrono>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int i, j;

  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin;
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end;

//  std::chrono::duration<long int, std::micro> duration;

  std::vector<std::chrono::duration<long int, std::micro> > times;

  for (i=0 ; i<10 ; ++i) {

    begin=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (j=0 ; j<1000000 ; ++j) {
      // Do things
    }
    end=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-begin).count();

    times.push_back(duration);

  }


  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I compile, I got this error. Gcc consider the vector as a `long int` vector, and I don't understand why.

```
test.cpp:28:29: erreur: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> > >::push_back(long int&)’
     times.push_back(duration);
```

I also tried to declare the variable `duration` before the first loop, like the [cpp reference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration) (and without the auto). But, when I try to assign it a value I got this error:

```
test.cpp:26:13: erreur: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> >’ and ‘std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> >::rep {aka long int}’)
     duration=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-begin).count();
```

My questions:

- How do I have to declare the variable `duration` (without the `auto`)?
- How do I have to declare the `times` vector ?

Comment: `sed s/stdlib.h/cstdlib/`

Comment: In the first message, it's not the vector's elements that are `long int`, but the value you're trying to add to it.

Comment: @molbdnilo, you're right. I interpreted/comment the error a little bit too fast

Comment: @kebs can you develop your comment please?

Comment: With C++, you'd better use cstdlib then stdlib.h (which is a C header). Won't change anything on your problem, just a side comment. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, just remove the `.count()` at the end of line in which you initialize `duration`.

> - How do I have to declare the variable duration (without the auto)?
> - How do I have to declare the times vector ?

The most readable form is a type alias, e.g.

```
using Duration = std::chrono::microseconds;

std::vector<Duration> times;

const Duration d = std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(end - begin);

times.push_back(d);
```

Note that I have dropped the explicit representation template parameter `long int`. The default helper types that `<chrono>` provides (here, `std::chrono::microseconds`) are fine.