# How come optimization makes a (potentially) complicated code beat a really small compact one in iterating through a hashtable?

Tags: c++, optimization, hashtable, unordered-map

### Background

Consider the [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) with closed addressing/separate chaining:

```cpp
// After inserting 16

|*  0 *| --> {499996, 4}
|*  1 *| --> {499994, 6}
|*  2 *|
|*  3 *| --> {499987, 13} --> {499998, 2}
|*  4 *|
|*  5 *| --> {499984, 16} --> {499986, 14}
|*  6 *|
|*  7 *| --> {499999, 1}
|*  8 *| --> {499985, 15} --> {499997, 3}
|*  9 *| --> {499989, 11} --> {499995, 5}
|* 10 *| --> {499988, 12} --> {500000, 0}
|* 11 *| --> {499993, 7}
|* 12 *|
|* 13 *| --> {499990, 10}
|* 14 *| --> {499991, 9} --> {499992, 8}
|* 15 *|
```

Typically, we can have two different schemes to link through all the nodes. One is to link the last node of the current bucket to the first node of the next non-empty bucket. See the above picture and imagine taht there are links among these buckets. Another is to make all the nodes look exactly the same as the above picture (by which I mean to link the tail nodes with null pointers).

The second approach will have some more work to obtain the successor of the current node. It may need to scan a lot of (empty) buckets to get its successor. Sounds awful, huh? Actually not. By amortized analysis (assume the `max_load_factor==1` ), ideally, we will have each node in a (different) bucket exactly. So it can be efficient.

How about the first one? The bad news is that it can suffer from very terrible insertion overhead. Now imagine you have a very big hashtable, `tab[i]` and `tab[j]` are two adjacent (non-empty) buckets. The horrible thing is that you have a very big difference `|i-j|`, and then an item whose hash code `k` is between `i` and `j` is needed to be inserted there. We will need to scan all the way down from `k` to `j` in order to update the links of the three nodes: the last node of bucket `i`, the newly inserted node, the first node of bucket `j` (you can think of this process as the insertion of a doubly-linked list). And if we constantly perform this pathological operation, `j-1, i+1, j-2, i+2,...`, things can get really bad.

### The Problem

After building a hashtable, we iterate through all the elements, which do you think is faster, the all-linked-up one (1st case) or the only-in-bucket-linked one (2nd case)?

Here is a piece of test code and the whole code can be found [here](https://github.com/How-u-doing/DataStructures/tree/master/Searching/HashMap/comp).

```cpp
int main()
{
#if   defined(USE_HASHMAP)
    mySymbolTable::HashMap<int, int> mp{};
#elif defined(USE_HASHMAP2)
    mySymbolTable::alternative::HashMap<int, int> mp{};
#else
    std::unordered_map<int, int> mp{};
#endif

    constexpr int N = 1'000'000;
    int k = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < N; ++i)
        mp[N-i] = i;

    auto t1 = std::clock();
    for(auto it=mp.begin(); it!=mp.end(); ++it)
        ++k;
    auto t2= std::clock();

    auto iteration_time_elapsed = (t2 - t1) / (double)1'000;
    std::cout << "Iterating through " << k << " items used "
              << iteration_time_elapsed << "ms\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Essentially, they run the following code respectively

```cpp
_self& operator++() {
    _ptr = _ptr->_next;
    return *this;
}
```

vs

```cpp
_self& operator++() {
    auto next = _table->next_entry(_ptr, _bucket_index);
    _ptr = next.first;
    _bucket_index = next.second;
    return *this;
}

std::pair<node_ptr, size_t> next_entry(node_ptr x, size_t bucket_index) const {
    assert(x != nullptr && "cannot increment end() iterator");
    if (x->_next) return { x->_next, bucket_index };
    size_t i = bucket_index + 1;
    for (; i < _hashtable.size(); ++i) {
        if (_hashtable[i]) return { _hashtable[i], i };
    }
    return { nullptr, i };
}
```

The bizarre thing is that in debug mode (`-g` flag), the 1st case beats the 2nd by about one fifth (`t1 = 82% * t2`), which is expected; while if optimization is enabled (`-O3` flag), it’s a whole different story. The summary tables are given below (or you can view the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igoHb.png)).

| test_d | test1_d | test2_d | test_int_d | test_int1_d<sup>1</sup> | test_int2_d | test_int_hash_d | test_int_hash1_d | test_int_hash2_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 114.993ms | 144.856ms | 175.616ms | 27.138ms |  | 58.631ms | 100.589ms | 138.219ms | 168.292ms |

| test | test1 | test2 | test_int | test_int1 | test_int2 | test_int_hash | test_int_hash1 | test_int_hash2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 108.126ms | 141.825ms | 32.269ms | 5.564ms | 5.777ms | 5.032ms | 93.445ms | 139.476ms | 31.251ms |

Here, `_d` suffix means debug version, `*1` suffix means [`myst::HashMap`](https://github.com/How-u-doing/DataStructures/blob/master/Searching/HashMap/Hashtable_impl.h) (1st case), `*2` suffix means [`myst::alternative::HashMap`](https://github.com/How-u-doing/DataStructures/blob/master/Searching/HashMap/alternative/Hashtable2_impl.h) (2nd case), and no suffix suggests we are using `std::unordered_map`.

We can see from the results that optimization `-O3` barely boosts the performance of the 1st case (`std::unordered_map` and `myst::HashMap`) except the `test_int` cases, but rather make a significant boost in the 2nd case (`myst::alternative::HashMap`). Given the 2nd is a little bit more complicated, it is therefore expected there will be more space for the 2nd case to optimize, for example, inlining. Still, I don’t think it can beat the 1st small code. How do we explain this weird phenomenon?

(In my understanding, small code means fast, think about cache, and technically speaking, 2nd case should never be faster than the 1st one.)

Any comments are appreciated.

<sup><sup>1</sup> It took a painfully long time even for optimized version to build the table. View the results [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igoHb.png). It seemed to have something to do with the hash function, I used another hash function found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996028) and it seemed to work well.</sup>

Comment: there isn't a direct correlation between code size and speed, making code bigger (e.g. loop unrolling) can make it faster

Comment: That's not much different from your [previous, now deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71252286). Your idea that _"small code means fast"_ is still wrong. E.g. the code for bubble sort is _much_ smaller than for quicksort, but quicksort is much faster. And yes, optimization can do crazy things.

Comment: @churill Thanks for your commenting. Sorry that I didn't make it clear: "small code means fast" of course I meant, under the same algorithm complexity or using the same algorithm. It wouldn't make sense to associate the code size with performance on different algorithms.  But here these two hash tables were constructed using the same algorithms and if you debug them (use `mp.print()`) you can see same structure.  And we're here to compare the iterating speed of these two node-linking schemes. And the results turned out quite surprising in optimized mode.

Comment: @churill What optimization technique(s) does the compiler use to make this
happen really amazed me. And I'm seeking for explanations. 
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)
At first I was thinking it was possibly because of CPU instruction pipelining,
instruction reordering/rescheduling etc., maybe. But wait a minute, I only
have "one" simple instruction (`_ptr = _ptr->_next;`) in the 1st case while
at least a few more instructions in the 2nd. I just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: The compiler sucking at optimizing simple instructions (though doesn't have that much space as compared to the 2nd) is really lame. I believe there must be a rational explanation for it.  BTW, 1st-case iterator only contains a node pointer whereas the 2nd contains a table pointer, a bucket index, and a node pointer. I'm not sure if this is the problem, the fat iterator shines :)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for pointing out this. But I didn't ever want/intend to associate code size with speed, maybe it was because of the title (a bit confusing, but I haven't figured out a better one. Hashtable-iterating schemes comparisons??). Anyway,  all I was/am confused about is why all-nodes-linked-up iteration be slower than each-bucket-linked-up iteration. How come? How possible? I also made a few other comments which may give some (helpful) information. Please check them out. Thank ya! If you have any further confusion/question(s), please comment.

Comment: @MarkTaylor Yes, of course, that example was a bit exaggerated :) Maybe you could also fine tune your meassurement. `clock()` isn't exactly reliable.  Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337278/precise-time-measurement) points out some alternatives. There are also some other effects like Cache/Cpu warmup, so you could try to iterate twice, but only meassure the second one.

Comment: @churill Thanks for your advices. I just tested clocking 2nd, 3rd iteration, used a different clocking system `chrono::high_resolution_clock`, still it didn't change anything. BTW, IMHO, I think the most accurate way to clock a code snippet is to use a system call. And a few days before while I was searching for fast string-sorting algorithms, I found https://github.com/rantala/string-sorting/blob/master/src/util/timing.c this may be more accurate for clocking. But I haven't tested it yet.